# Loading caret namespace invokes random function?

Tags: r, r-caret

In loading namespace for `caret` package, I found following situation:

```
# 1.
set.seed(1)
print(rnorm(1))           # -0.6264538

# 2. Restart R session

# 3.
set.seed(1)
loadNamespace('caret')
print(rnorm(1))           # -0.3262334

# 4. Restart R session

# 5.
loadNamespace('caret')
set.seed(1)
loadNamespace('caret')
print(rnorm(1))           # -0.6264538
```

This gave me trouble when I write unit-testing codes for some functions in which the `caret` namespace is loaded. An example is as follows:

File `R/abn.R`:

```
abn <- function(){
  requireNamespace('caret')
  round(rnorm(1), 5)
}
```

File `tests/testthat/test_abn.R`:

```
context("Test abnomality")

test_that("Anomaly situation", {
  requireNamespace('caret') # Without this line, devtools::check() will fail
                            #   abn() not equal to -0.62645.
                            #   1/1 mismatches
                            #   [1] -0.326 - -0.626 == 0.3
  set.seed(1)
  expect_equal(abn(), -0.62645)
})
```

You can see my workaround solution.

Do I miss something here?

Is there an authentic way to avoid this situation?

Or, this workaround might help persons in similar trouble.

Comment: Seems like good practice to use `set.seed()`. I don't see a need for a "workaround".

Comment: You're right. I can use -0.32623 for unit testing in the example. But actions such as loading namespaces can be repeated in the code and if caret is already loaded, the test will fail. Although not exampled, I experienced the pass-the-test but fail-at-check situation and solved that situation with that workaround. Anyway, most of all, I'm not sure we should mind this kind of side effect when loading namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really missed anything. The [question has come up before](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/452) and it is related to some packages create random startup messages. It took me a while to originally track it down.

Comment: This helps. However, it would have been better if I missed something. R world is fantastic but using R language is sometimes tricky. I hope package developers introducing some opposite-protection features that prevent programmers from making hard-to-find bugs.